# Django endless pagination Digg-style pagination doesn't work

Tags: jquery, django, pagination, django-endless-pagination

I'm trying to use Django pagination endless and it works perfectly styled Twitter and on a roll. It does not work in style Digg. Unfortunately I need Digg Style in my app. This is my code:

View.py

```
from endless_pagination.decorators import page_template    

@page_template('template_page.html')
def my_view(request, template='template.html', extra_context=None, ord=3):
    # some code to setting variable to pass to the template.html
    var = 2
    var = 1        
    my_data = my_data.objects.all()

    context = {
           'my_data':my_data, 
           'var1': var1,
           'var2': var2, 
           'my_data' : my_data,
              }
    if extra_context is not None:
       context.update(extra_context)

    return render_to_response(template, context,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template.html

```
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <div class="endless_page_template">
               {% include page_template %}
            </div>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="/static/assets/scripts/endless_pagination/js/endless-pagination.js"></script>

    <script>    
       $(document).ready(function() {
           $.endlessPaginate();
       });      
    </script>
```

template_page.html

```
    {% load endless %}                          
    {% paginate my_data %}

    {% for data in my_data  %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
    {% get_pages %}
    {% if pages.paginated %}        
        {{ pages }}
    {% endif %}
```

If I click on pages number, nothing happens (no page refresh, no ajax call, etc.). Where is the problem? Thanks a lot. In console nothing happens

Comment: I know this is late, but do you have any errors in browser console?